# In PHP, exec fails silently, sometimes, when calling many exec commands, but the same command run again later will work

Tags: php, multithreading, exec

I have a PHP script that uses exec('command args > /log/file &'); within a loop to create multiple child scripts that run at the same time. Basically, the parent script gets user information out of a database and creates child scripts running in parallel, then the child script creates an email to send to a single user. This happens approximately 50,000 times.

To prevent the creation of 50,000 simultaneously running processes, I have a database table that keeps track of the currently running processes, and before creating a new process the parent checks the current child count and sleeps if 25 children are currently active. The child, upon completing its task, deletes its row in the table, freeing the parent to create more children.

The problem is, about 10% of the exec commands fail silently, and for seemingly no reason. I can run the parent script again (it's smart enough not to email the same user twice), and it will work, once again, 90% of the time using the same exec commands that failed last time. Running the script five or six times in a row will email everyone.

By putting a sleep immediately after the exec, I can increase my success rate to around 95%.

Why would exec be failing, if the same command will work later? I can just keep the script repeating until it completes, but I'd much rather solve the exec problem.

Some highly simplified sample code:

Parent script:

```
do {
    //get user, group, and supergroup information for users that haven't
    //been emailed yet
    foreach ($users as $userArray) {
        $processId = insertIntoProcessQueue($userArray);
        $cmd = 'sudo php -q ./childScript.php ' . cliArg($userArray) . ' ' . 
               cliArg($groupArray) . ' ' . cliArg($supergroupArray)
               ' ' . $proccessId . ' > file.log &';
        exec($cmd);
        do {
            if (numChildren() >= 25) {
                sleep(1);
                $waiting = true;
            }
        } while ($waiting);
    }
    $incomplete = moreUsersToEmail() > 0 ? true : false;
} while ($incomplete);

function cliArg($array) {
    return escapeshellarg(json_encode($arg));
}
```

Child script:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
$user = json_decode($argv[1]);
$group = json_decode($argv[2]);
$supergroup = json_decode($argv[3]);

print_r($user);

$email = createEmail($user, $group, $supergroup);

$email->sendEmail();
removeFromProcessQueue($argv[4]);
flush();
exit;
```

The print_r will only show up in the log file when the script completes and I never get any errors, so I can't get any data about why it's failing. To add to that, it doesn't fail consistently on any individual users, and it doesn't fail running a single user at a time, so I have to run the script through everyone and try and catch the errors amidst the 45,000 that are working properly. And, since the parent and child never communicate beyond the parent starting the child, I can't detect (from the parent) when a child fails (otherwise I could immediately try and start any failed children again instead of rerunning the parent post-hoc).

Edit: So it turns out there's an included script that's dynamically generated and is destroyed and regenerated every time it's used (don't ask me why), which creates a race condition while running processes in parallel that caused the script to fail.

Thanks everyone for your unfortunately wasted time.

Comment: tried checking the return value of `exec`?

Comment: (also this is a bad way to send emails. Just loop. You won't benefit from splitting it across processes, because the network is the bottleneck)

Comment: Could it be that you're feeding your host's mail system with too much stuff at once? Is the mortality rate still as high when you lower the thread count to a very sane value, like 2?

Comment: How do you know the exec commands are failing? Is it because you do not see the processes getting pulled off the queue, or because emails are not showing up?

Comment: The return value of exec is null because I'm purposefully sending the output to a log file. It's not JUST sending emails. Building the emails is what's taking time.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php `3:&$return_var` might be interesting to see if the script throws an error (`>=1`) or completes successfully (`=0`). I think you can just skip `2:&$output` by feeding it an empty array.

Comment: The mail system isn't a problem. There's a mail queue that keeps track of what emails need to be sent, and it sends the emails at a sane pace. I know the exec commands are failing because they won't print anything to the log file, won't send emails, and won't touch the database.

Comment: Well then, could your system be hitting some limits? Things like AppArmor or SELinux like to limit the number of processes a user can start and even the stock linux kernel itself has some similar things. Although you shouldn't really be hitting that with just 25 processes unless the same user is running some other intensive things. I think intercepting the `stderr` pipe from the child processes might be your best bet at debugging this! Add `2>&1` to the spawning command before the final `&`.

Comment: Limiting the number of children to 4 did not help. The stderr piping had no effect (nothing in the log file). The return_var of exec is "0" even when the execution fails.

Comment: you can use `exit(1);` to return a value into `$return_var = exec($cmd)`; the script may also fail when you do `removeFromProcessQueue` in the child process instead of in the parent process (where most likely your queue was defined)

Comment: The queue is just a database table with the process information, so there shouldn't be a process conflict. For returning, I've seen no evidence that on a failure anything within the child script is executed (prints, echos, exits, etc.).

Comment: you will not solve, but will no more need to restart main process if you call 
`insertIntoProcessQueue();`
`removeFromProcessQueue();`
both from the child process

Comment: What does the flag `-q`? Looks like quite

Comment: Since you answered the question yourself, post your solution as an answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Was there [any solution](http://xkcd.com/979/)? If there's an answer here, I seem to miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there's an included script that's dynamically generated and is destroyed and regenerated every time it's used (don't ask me why), which creates a race condition while running processes in parallel that caused the script to fail.

Thanks everyone for your unfortunately wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at [the PHP docs for exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and you can pass an array as a reference with a second parameter which will be filled with the output of exec.  You can use this to determine a) why the command is failing and b) when the command fails and integrate that into your code.

So I'd change:

```
exec($cmd);
```

To something like:

```
function check_exec_results($results)
{
    echo '<HR><PRE>',print_r($output,true),'</PRE><HR>'; //use this to figure out what output you're getting from the exec commands then remove when you've figured out a way to set $results_look_good below

    $results_look_good = ?; //you will need to edit this yourself to actually do some kind of check

    return $results_look_good;        
}

$successful_exec = false;
do
{
    $exec_results = array();
    exec($cmd,$exec_results);
    $successful_exec = check_exec_results($exec_results);
}
while (!$successful_exec);
```

Note that this is potentially an infinite loop so I'd also go a step further and set a limit to the number of times exec() can be called for each user.